# powershell script does not run properly from a batch file

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have a functioning PowerShell script which registers a timer object and sends a key every couple of minutes.

```
$wshell = New-Object -ComObject Wscript.Shell    

...

function fctName {
    param([ScriptBlock] $action)

    ...

    Register-ObjectEvent -InputObject $timer -EventName Elapsed -SourceIdentifier Timer.Elapsed -Action $action
}

fctName {

    ...

    $wshell.sendkeys("{ESC}")
}
```

Within the Windows PowerShell ISE the script works just fine, without any errors.
But, I would love to run it from a batch file, in which I wrote only this line:

```
Powershell.exe -noexit C:\...\ScriptName.ps1
```

No errors are thrown but it does not do what I want, which is to prevent Windows going idle.

Because I '-noexit' the cmd window, I can easily stop the event with

```
Unregister-Event -SourceIdentifier Timer.Elapsed
```

It seems to be working because only typing it twice throws an error.

- Could it be that my batch file needs different code?
  Maybe "echo" etc. I'm not very familiar with it
- Could it be that I have to import a module in Powershell?

Comment: I think the problem is that scheduled tasks living in a different session/context respect to the one of the logged user. SendKeys aren't send in the actual user session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not that comfortable with PowerShell, but in JScript you could use this code:

```
var osh = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell")
WSH.Echo(
    /cscript/i.test(WSH.FullName)
    ? 'Anti-idle running. Hit Ctrl-C to exit'
    : "Anti-idle running.\nTo stop, use task manager to kill wscript.exe"
);
while (1) {
    WSH.Sleep(120 * 1000);
    osh.SendKeys("{SCROLLLOCK}{SCROLLLOCK}");
}
```

Save that with a `.js` extension and you can double-click it to launch it, or launch it from a `cmd` console via `cscript /nologo scriptfile.js`.

I think toggling Scroll Lock is more benign than sending Esc, as Esc could have unwanted consequences depending on what application happens to have focus when the `SendKeys` line fires.

---

Does PowerShell have access to Windows Script Host methods like `Sleep`?  Apparently so with [Start-Sleep](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee177002.aspx).  That might be preferable to spawning a timer.  Hopefully if my JScript code isn't suitable natively for your evil purposes, it will at least be suitable as pseudocode for your PowerShell script.

Comment: True story. Works only with SendKeys, such as [System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys]::SendWait("{SCROLLLOCK}{SCROLLLOCK}") and the Start-Sleep function in PowerShell within a loop.